# Update particular contribute based on contribute id with civicrm_api3

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

I am working with civi 5.10. How can i update the conribution table row based on contribute id .  I want replace that below  code with civicrm_api3().

```
        db_update('civicrm_contribution') // Table name no longer needs {}
        ->fields(array(
        'contribution_status_id' => $contribution_status_id,
        ))
        ->condition('id', $contrib_data[0]->id, '=')
        ->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [civicrm api](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/) to process CRUD on CiviCRM Database.

To update contribution you can use

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'create', [
  'id' => $contrib_data[0]->id,
  'contribution_status_id' => $contribution_status_id,
]);
```

Cheers

Pradeep